# Не могу передать число из переменной jquery в калькулятор

Tags: jquery

Всем доброго дня.

Есть калькулятор, который принимает значения из двух селектов, и из двух переменных, которые получают числа после клика на кнопку "Купить".

**Проблема вот в чем** - из селектов все работает, а передать значения из двух других переменных не получается, это var klishe и  var osnastka. При том, что они точно получают числовые значений, при выводе на страницу выводят целые числа. А в калькулятор не передаются.

summ(); для них вставлял для пробы, для эксперимента.

Подскажите, в чем я туплю?
Большое спасибо за ответ!
**Спасибо огромное всем за помощь!**

```js
 // калькулятор

    var numbosnauto=0, time=1, osnastka=0, klishe=0, shipp=0; 
 
 // выдирание текста и чисел
 // Оттиски
 
  jQuery("#modal_form-c .add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
    let price = jQuery(this).closest('ul').find(".price").text();
   var klishe = price.match(/\d+/);
    jQuery("#ott-price").text(price);
   summ();
   
  let prodname = jQuery(this).closest('ul').find(".title").text(); 
       jQuery("#ott-name").text( prodname );
  

});
 
 // Оснастки авто
  jQuery("#modal_osn1 .add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
    let priceosnauto = jQuery(this).closest('ul').find(".price").text();
   var osnastka = priceosnauto.match(/\d+/);
    jQuery("#osn").text(priceosnauto);
      summ();

  let prodnameosnauto = jQuery(this).closest('ul').find(".title").text(); 
       jQuery("#prodosn").text( prodnameosnauto );
  
});
 
  // тут два работающих селекта
jQuery("#time").change(function(){
           time = jQuery('#time').val();
    summ();
});

jQuery("#shipp").change(function(){
    var shipptext = jQuery('#shipp').val();
 shipp = shipptext.match(/\d+/);
    jQuery("#sh").text(shipp + ' руб.' );
    summ();
    
});



function summ(){    
 
klishe = Number(klishe);
   
     osnastka = Number(osnastka);

    time = Number(time);

    shipp = Number(shipp);
    
    jQuery("#summ").text(osnastka+klishe*time+shipp + ' руб.' );

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша "глобальная" переменная `klishe` определена внутри другой функции, скорее всего - внутри обработчика `$(document).ready`. А функция `summ` находится вне этого обработчика и не "видит" эту переменную. Покажите код полностью, и Вам скажут куда и что подвинуть, чтобы это заработало.

Comment: скорее всего - внутри обработчика $(document).ready - Точно!   Спасибо огромное всем за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

var osnastka и klishe являются локальными переменными и доступны только внутри своих функций. Вне функций их одноименные переменные имеют значение 0.

Конкретную реализацию не подскажу, но направления такие:

Первый вариант - переменная передаётся как аргумент функции.

```
    var klishe=0;
    function test (){
         var klishe = 1;
         summ(klishe);
    };
    function summ(klishe){    
    klishe = Number(klishe);
    console.log(klishe);
    };
    test();
```

Второй вариант - глобальной переменной присваивается результат выполнения функции

```
var klishe = 0;
function test (){
            var klishe = 1;
            return klishe;
    };
klishe = test();
function summ() {    
    klishe = Number(klishe);
    console.log(klishe);
    };
summ();
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А не подскажете, как решить проблему ?

Comment: Вижу два варианта - либо передавать в summ эту переменную как аргумент, или указать функции возвращать (return) эту подсчитанную переменную и присваивать значение глобальной.

Comment: Большое спасибо! пробую!

Comment: @Максим Привел тестовые примеры в ответе.

Comment: Правда, я не знаю как, никогда раньше не делал)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Пробую.

Comment: Пробовал соединить ваш код со своим, но ничего не получилось. Не хватает знаний, наверно синтаксиса. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Максим Попробуйте просто заменить var klishe = price.match(/\d+/); на klishe = price.match(/\d+/); (без var). Этим вы будете сразу менять значение глобальной переменной.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var klishe = 0, times=1, osnastka=0, shipp=0; 
 
 // выдирание текста и чисел
 // Оттиски
 
  jQuery("#modal_form-c .add_to_cart_button").click(function(){
    let price = jQuery(this).closest('ul').find(".price").text();
   var klishe = price.match(/\d+/);
    jQuery("#ott-price").text(price);
   
  let prodname = jQuery(this).closest('ul').find(".title").text(); 
       jQuery("#ott-name").text( prodname );
 });
```

Пробовал соединить этот свой код с вашим

```js
var klishe = 0;
function test (){
            var klishe = 1;
            return klishe;
    };
klishe = test();
function summ() {    
    klishe = Number(klishe);
    console.log(klishe);
    };
summ();
```

Но ничего не получилось. Не хватает знаний.  Помогите, пожалуйста.

Понимаю глупость вопроса, но что делать с новым кодом? куда вставлять? как соединить со своим? вставлять до него или после?  просто заменить var klishe - не помогло. Спасибо за терпение.

Comment: `/*var*/ klishe = price.match(/\d+/);`

Comment: Понимаю глупость вопроса, но что делать с новым кодом? куда вставлять? как соединить со своим? вставлять до него или после?  просто заменить var klishe - не помогло. Спасибо за терпение.

Comment: Создайте (в вопросе) работающий пример с разметкой, который воспроизводит Вашу проблему. Непонятно, когда и где Вы используете переменную `klishe`.

Comment: я ее использую в function summ() в самом низу примера, в моем вопросе. var klishe и var osnastka в калькулятор не передаются. Это весь код, другого нет. Создать работающий пример не могу, скрипт получает числа по клику на Купить товар

Comment: Что значит "не передаются"? Чему эта переменная равна внутри `summ`? `console.log(klishe);`

Comment: ReferenceError: klishe is not defined